# what does tomcat docker comes with by default?

Tags: docker, tomcat

I am fairly new to docker. I was looking into docker hub and found that there is a docker image for tomcat which can be downloaded using docker pull tomcat. So my question is how can I know what does this image contains. Is there an underlying OS and then tomcat is installed on top of it. how can I know all the details about the docker image?

Comment: You can check the official Dockerfile for the version of Tomcat docker image you want to use. E.g. https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/9.0/jdk8/openjdk/Dockerfile
this one is based on openjdk:8-jdk docker image, on top of it there were installed some libs/packages

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the link in the comment, visit the link and you will see everything in that Dockerfile.

So if you visit [openjdk/Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/9.0/jdk8/openjdk/Dockerfile) you will see the list of packages and some base image.

Better to use that images from the Dockerhub which Dockerfile is given.

In simple word, your image only contains the OS or packages that are defined in Dockerfile.

[image]

This is the dockerfile that define every thing and the container will only contain that packages that are defined in Dockerfile. You should not ignore based image in Dockerfile too.